# prove that a set a can have at most one supremum.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, supremum-and-infimum

prove that a set a can have at most one supremum.

My answer is:

To prove the claim consider the case that there are two (or more) supremum $a$ and $a′$ of a set $A$. Then for every element $x$ of $A$:

$x≤a$ (from the definition of supremum) & $x≤a′$ (from the definition of supremum).

So $a′≤a$(a′ is the supremum of A ) and $a≤a′$(a is the supremum of A).

Now by antisymmetry $a′=a$.

Am I correct?

Comment: I assume by the tags that we are working with subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ and the usual ordering?

Comment: yes I do @TheoBendit

Comment: It seems that you're assuming that $a, a' \in A$, which means you're proving the uniqueness of maxima, not suprema.

Comment: when you state that $a' \leq a$ and $a \leq a'$ you should note that you are applying the definition that $sup A$ is the least upper bound which is what allows you to relate the 2 values $a$ and $a'$ in this way. Then, by anitsymmetry you have what you set out to prove. Otherwise, this looks correct assuming that the supremum exists.

Comment: @theo He is not making that assumption if he makes the statement from the definition of supremum. The way it is written now, seems to risk assuming $sup A \in A \implies sup A = max A$, but this shouldn't be necessary

Comment: @rjm27trekkie  I think if the question asks me to prove the existence of sup it will say "prove that a set a can have at least one supremum." .... correct?

Comment: Yes, it would ask to you to prove the supremum exists. I lost points on a quiz in real analysis for not considering the case where the supremum of A did not exist when showing a relation such as the one about though. you should simply state the relationship wouldn't hold if the supremum doesn't exist, but you don't have to prove that it exists to show the relationship is true if it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your proof assumes that the supremum is an element of the set.
Note that if you have two supremum then both of them are upper bounds and both of them are the least upper bound. Since the first one is the least upper bound and the second one is an upper bound, the the first one is less than or equal the second one. Similarly the second one is less than or equal to the first one,

Thus they are equal and as the result the supremum is unique.